# Do Flux (by Facebook) handle server side update with sockets

Tags: javascript, sockets, reactjs, flux

I'm looking for [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html) combined with [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) and I read a lot's about Dispatcher, Actions and Store. But I didn't understand if Flux handle (natively) data update on server side by broadcasting sockets as 'Actions' ? (like [MeteorJS](https://www.meteor.com/) do with [publish/subscribe](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/publish-and-subscribe))

Or do I have to handle an external API and sockets call alone ?

Comment: Are you asking if the API supports it or if the Flux pattern can handle it? Remember, `react-flux` and Flux are different things.

Comment: I know with Meteor, if a client update data. Server will inform others clients looking for this data (directly with socket). I'm asking if React Flux do the same things with Actions ? Or if it's only used to handle client side data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not handled by the library at all. Any implementation of this functionality would need to happen in user code (or in some other library).

Comment: Humm okay.. So, meteor seems to be the best for quick apps.